# How display a json error message?

Tags: json.net

I cannot display the Json message, Im trying prevente that user upload files with same name this is my controller code:

```
     //POST: /Quote/Create   Save the Uploaded file
    public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile(int? chunk, string name)
    {
        bool exists;
        var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
        var uploadPath = "C:\\Files";        
        chunk = chunk ?? 0;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(uploadPath, name)))
        {
            exists = true;
        }
        else {
            exists = false;
        }
        if (!exists)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, name), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
                fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else {
            return Json(new { success = false, Message = "The file" + name +"already exists" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

This is my view code, if files success is false, then display the Json message:

```
            UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
            if (!files.success) {

                alert(files.Message);
                console.log(up);
            } else {
                var j = 0;
                if (count > 0) {
                    j = count;
                } else {
                    j = @i + '';
                }
                $.each(files, function (i, file) {

                    var extension = file.name.split(".");

                    $('.files').append('<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Files[' + j + '].Name\" value=\"' + file.name + '\" />');
                    $('.files').append('<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Files[' + j + '].Date\" value=\"' + "@DateTime.Now" + '\" />');
                    j++;
                });
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Need to post more of your javascript please. And shouldn't it be `alert(files.Message)`?

Comment: thanks I edited my question, files.Message is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to be returning a string result rather than an `ActionResult`, since all you really want is if it passed or not. Also shortened your code a little to reflect the changes.

If you did want to return an object (meaning you wanted more than one property), I would create a model (class and then object), then return `JsonResult` rather than `ActionResult`.

[Good documentation on how to return JsonResult object](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/)

**C#**

```
public string SaveUploadedFile(int? chunk, string name)
{
    bool exists = false;
    var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
    var uploadPath = "C:\\Files";        
    chunk = chunk ?? 0;
    exists = System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(uploadPath, name));

    if (!exists)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, name), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
     }

     return message = !exists ? string.Empty
                              : "The file" + name + " already exists";
}
```

**Javascript**

```
if (files.message != '') {   // meaning "exists" is true
     console.log(up);
} else {
     ......
     ......
}
```

Comment: thanks but I don't have problems sending the message, I have problems reading the message from the response to display an alert I tried your code and yep it also sends the message but I don't know how to display in an alert.          with your code, this is the response {"The fileDesert.jpgalready exists"}    and with my code  {"success":false,"Message":"The fileDesert.jpgalready exists"}

Comment: can you post more of your javascript code, where you call the method (MVC) and return the object